How to add single quotes to one of the columns in PowerShell?
I have the following lines in a file:
pc_cc_text$fx_review1  CONSTANT VARCHAR2(100) := 'For Company Review'; -- AD_PRT_AUTH_(MSP)
pc_cc_text$fx_review2  CONSTANT VARCHAR2(100) := 'For Dept Review'; -- AD_PRT_AUTH_(ADX)

I need to format them as follows:
WHEN 'pc_cc_text$fx_review1' THEN 'For Company Review' 
WHEN 'pc_cc_text$fx_review2' THEN 'For Dept Review'

How to do this in PowerShell?
This is what I have tried so far:
(Get-Content FILE | where {$_ -match ':='} | where {$_ -notmatch '^--'} | ForEach-Object{("'" + $_ -split ";|--")[0,1] -join ''}) -replace 'CONSTANT[^ ]'  -replace 'VARCHAR2[^ ]' -replace ':=', 'THEN ' -replace '^', 'WHEN '

This prints:
WHEN 'pc_cc_text$fx_review1    THEN  'For Company Review'
WHEN 'pc_cc_text$fx_review2    THEN  'For Dept Review'

It is almost correct but the second single tick on the second column needs to be added. How to do this?

Do you really need v2 compatibility? Please use only one versioned tag, namely for the minimum version your code must support.


It is more concise and more efficient to use a single -replace operation:
Get-Content FILE | 
  Where-Object { $_ -notmatch '^--' -and $_ -match ':=' } | 
  ForEach-Object {
    $_ -replace '^(\S+).+?:= *(''.+?'');.*$', 'WHEN ''$1''    THEN  $2'
  }


The regex above is designed to consume the entire input string and to use capture groups ((...)) to capture the substrings of interest.

What the capture groups captured can then be referred to in the substitution expression as $1 for the 1st capture group, and so on.

Since the regex matches the entire input string, it is effectively replaced by what the substitution expression evaluates to.

For an explanation of the regex and substitution operation and the option to experiment with them, see this regex101.com page (note that since "..." quoting is implied on the site, the embedded ' chars. do not need escaping as '').



Alternatively, if you want to stick with your -split-based approach:
Get-Content FILE | 
  Where-Object { $_ -notmatch '^--' -and $_ -match ':=' } | 
  ForEach-Object{
    $first, $second = ($_ -split ' +\w+ +\w+(?:\(\d+\))? +:= +|;')[0,1]
    "WHEN '$first'    THEN  $second"
  }


The  +\w+ +\w+(?:\(\d+\))? +:= + part of the regex matches  CONSTANT VARCHAR2(100) := and similar strings; combined with alternatively (|) splitting by ;, the first 2 resulting tokens ([0,1]) are the ones of interest.

These tokens are stored in variables $first and $second, respectively, and are used in an expandable (interpolating), double-quoted string ("...") to produce the desired output, which makes it easy to place ' on both sides of the first token.



Thanks. Both solutions didn't work. It printed as follows:
code
WHEN 'pc_cc_text$fx_review1   ' THEN  'For Company Review'
WHEN 'pc_cc_text$fx_review2   ' THEN  'For Dept Review'
code
With extra gaps after the second column before the second tick.

@user27817415: Please see my update, which now uses more flexible regex patterns to match variable amounts of whitespace. In the future, to avoid this back and forth, please provide representative sample input in your question and describe all variations that must be handled.

The simplest modification of your code is to change one of your -replace methods so that it replaces the text with the single quote instead of replacing it with nothing. You will also need to consume the preceding spaces in the text you replace.
-replace 'CONSTANT[^ ]'

changed to:
-replace '\s*CONSTANT[^ ]', "'"

A better solution is to perform everything in a single action. You can use the -replace that mklement0 suggested, which works great, or I'll offer an alternative based on capturing groups in the Where statement, automatic  and string formatting.
Get-Content FILE | 
    where {$_ -notmatch '^--' -and $_ -match "^(.+?\S)\s*CONSTANT.*?:=.*?('.+?')"} |
    ForEach-Object {
        "WHEN '{0}' THEN {1}" -f $Matches[1], $Matches[2]
    }

It should effectively do the same thing as mklement0's -replace, just using string formatting and automatic variables instead.

Thanks, it worked but printed very few lines. Matching won't always be CONSTANT VARCHAR2. It can be CONSTANT NUMBER, CONSTANT DATE, CONSTANT VARCHAR, CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER etc. So how to expand the match condition?

The .*? matches anything, so I updated my answer to be more generic

A larger example of the file would be useful, especially to see what kind of lines you do NOT want to touch
That said:
$TextContent = Get-Content -Path $FilePath
$TextContent -replace "(\S+).+?'([^']*)'.*" , 'WHEN ''$1'' THEN ''$2'''

Basically takes the characters until the first space and the characters between the first wo successive single quotes(') and rewrite the line with those.
Have a example link
